# Adjust features with selectInput in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

The code below generates an output table according to the weights selected by `numericInput`. This is working fine. The method involved for calculation is the WSM (weighted sum model). For this method it is necessary to choose the weights, which is already being done correctly in the app below, and also if a certain criterion is to maximize or minimize. However, that last question is not being done automatically in code. Notice that it is like this:

```
scaled <- df1 |>
      mutate(Coverage = min(Coverage) / Coverage, #minimize
             
             Production = Production / max(Production)) #maximize
```

That is, I manually selected that `Coverage` is minimize and `Production` is maximize, but for example it could be the other way around. That's why I created two `selectInputs`, where the person chooses whether he wants to maximize or minimize a certain criterion. Now how can tweak this in the shiny code so that it stays automatically?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)
library(MCDM)

df1 <- structure(list(n = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), 
                      Coverage = c(0.0363201192049018, 0.0315198954715543,
                                   0.112661460735583, 0.112661460735583, 0.112661460735583, 0.0813721071219816,
                                   0.0862146652218061, 0.0697995564757394, 0.0599194966471805,
                                   0.0507632014547115), 
                      Production =
                        c(1635156.04305, 474707.64025, 170773.40775, 64708.312, 64708.312, 64708.312,
                          949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635, 949.72635)),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  
  column(4,
         wellPanel(
           numericInput("weight1",label = h4("Weight 1"), min = 0, max = 1, value = NA, step = 0.1),
           selectInput("maxmin1", label = h5("Maximize or Minimize?"),choices = list("Maximize " = 1, "Minimize" = 2), selected = ""),
         
           disabled(numericInput("weight2",label = h4("Weight 2"), min = 0,max = 1,value = NA,step = 0.1)),
           selectInput("maxmin2", label = h5("Maximize or Minimize?"),choices = list("Maximize " = 1, "Minimize" = 2), selected = ""),
           
           helpText("The sum of weights should be equal to 1")
         )),
  hr(),
  column(8,
         tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Method1", DTOutput('table1'))),
         tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Method2", DTOutput('table2')))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  scaled <- reactive({
    
    weights <- c(req(input$weight1), req(input$weight2))
    
    scaled <- df1 |>
      mutate(Coverage = min(Coverage) / Coverage, #minimize
             
             Production = Production / max(Production)) #maximize
    
    scaled <- scaled |>
      rowwise() |>
      mutate(`Performance Score` = weighted.mean(c(Coverage, Production), w = weights))
    
    scaled$Rank <- (nrow(scaled) + 1) - rank(scaled$`Performance Score`)
    
    scaled
    
    
  })
  

  observeEvent(input$weight1, {
    freezeReactiveValue(input, "weight2")
    updateNumericInput(session, 'weight2', value = 1 - input$weight1)
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    req(scaled())
    datatable(scaled(), options = list( columnDefs = list(list(
          className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all")),paging = TRUE,searching = FALSE,
        pageLength =  10, dom = 'tip',scrollX = TRUE),rownames = FALSE)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you help me understand "so that it stays automatically?" What do you actually mean here?  is Coverage corresponding to 1, and Production corresponding to 2?  Currently on the app, a user can choose both of these to be "Minimize" or both to be "Maximize". Do you want to limit it so that one is always min and one is always max?, or can they both be min or both be max (like currently in the app?)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make the following small change in the server function

```
    methods <- list("1" = max, "2" = min)
    funcs = c(methods[[req(input$maxmin1)]], methods[[req(input$maxmin2)]])
  
    scaled <- df1 |>
      mutate(Coverage = funcs[[1]](Coverage) / Coverage,
             Production = Production / funcs[[2]](Production))
```

Notice that I simply create a named list `methods` that has two elements, the first being the `max` function and the second being the `min` function. I have named this list as you have named the `choices` in the `input$maxmin1` and `input$maxmin2` objects. Then I create a vector `funcs` which simply selects the appropriate matching function from the list.  In the next lines, I use `funcs[[1]]` as the function to apply to `Coverage` and `funcs[[2]]` as the function to apply to `Production`

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks for replying. A question: See that `maximize` is already selected in `selectInput`, even though I inserted `selected = ""` em `ui`. Do you know how to adjust so that no option is selected, just like I did with the weights?